# WCF OperationContract return as XmlElement But Client App how do receive it

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

In WCF i declared as follows,

`[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFaultContract))]
[OperationContract][return: XmlElement("Customer")]
Customer GetCustomer(long CustID);`

And in WCFTest Client it retrives as XML in XmL Tab with values.

But Formatted tab it shows as null object.

Could anybody suggested How do i use in my ClientApp to retrieve the Customer Object from GetCustomer method?

For More information, i am using basicHttpBinding for binding opertaions.

Comment: Is the `Customer` object contained in the WSDL?

Comment: No. It does not contains the customer object.

Comment: Yes i am getting the Customer object in WSDL. But Client App the method is not returning the value. anybody can help.

Comment: I got the answer. IXmlSerializable.WriteXml should have constructed properly. ie., Adding in the writer stream should have the tags clearly.